# ASP.NET Core policy to allow all HttpGet requests

Tags: asp.net-core

I have been asked to create a read-all policy for my API. Can I Create a filter of some kind that allows all HttpGet actions?

I have this polices that I apply manual on each controller/actions

```
public static void AddPolicies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // APP_CE_READER
            options.AddPolicy("Reader", policy =>
                policy.RequireClaim("group", "89625d9c-6c0f-490e-8fe5-a06584b7a022"));
            // APP_CE_EDIT_CUSTOMER
            options.AddPolicy("EditCustomer", policy =>
                policy.RequireClaim("group", "5f56395d-99d7-4f96-bc89-08e7c2206fc7"));
            // APP_CE_EDIT_AGREEMENT
            options.AddPolicy("EditAgreement", policy =>
                policy.RequireClaim("group", "44cd2c55-9f78-440b-a77e-708e466433b4"));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a middleware and add it in the first of pipeline which reject all methods but get.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var options = context.RequestServices.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<ApiPolicyOptions>>();
    if (options.CurrentValue.ReadOnly && !HttpMethods.IsGet(context.Request.Method))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("Not allowed in read only mode");
    }
    else
    {
        return next();
    }
});

public class ApiPolicyOptions
{
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```